# Blackberry - How to get OS version information and number of applications

Tags: blackberry, system

Please advice the program (eclipse) to obtain operating system, version information and number of application in a blackberry device.

Answer (score 9):

os version: `DeviceInfo.getSoftwareVersion()`

number of running Apps:

```
ApplicationDescriptor[] ad = 
    ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager().getVisibleApplications();
int numberOfRunningApps = ad.length;
```

Comment: Thank you. i am new to blackberry application development, could you please suggest any book that would help me developing blackberry program

Comment: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/1076/development.pdf
This pdf is a good ebook for blackberry java app development.

Comment: This returns a String. Is there any documentation on the format of the string?