# Unable to find the BB10 OS Version in android Code after Porting

Tags: android

In Android Code the function Build.VERSION.RELEASE returns the android version of device running the application but After porting in blackberry the same code doesn't provide the blackberry OS version.

Is there any way to get blackberry OS version by porting Android code on blackberry.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static String getBlackberryVersion() {
    File file = new File("/etc/os.version");
    String osVersion = "";
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        osVersion = br.readLine();
        br.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    return "Blackberry " + osVersion;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, Android and Blackberry is different, you can't just move android code into blackberry code...

These links might answer your question :

[Blackberry - platform version and software version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066855/blackberry-platform-version-and-software-version)

[Blackberry - How to get OS version information and number of applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137793/blackberry-how-to-get-os-version-information-and-number-of-applications)

Good luck ^^

Comment: Hi, Thanks but these links(Code) are not working in android code after BB10 porting.